# Couple of questions about a passage

Tags: words

I was practicing the jlpt n3 audios and found the next passage:

男：山口さん、**帰らなくていいんですか**。6時までに「みなと市民ホール」に行くって言ってたじゃないですか。

女：市民ホールはみなと駅でしたよね。**ここからは電車で二つ目**ですから、まだ大丈夫ですよ

1)Why is it saying "Is it okay if you don't go home?" 「帰らなくていいんですか。」

2)What does 「ここから電車で二つ目」 mean?

悔しい質問ですから、申し訳ありません。

お願いします

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 男：山口さん、**帰らなくていいんですか**。6時までに「みなと市民ホール」に行くって言ってたじゃないですか。
>
> 女：市民ホールはみなと駅でしたよね。**ここからは電車で二つ目**ですから、まだ大丈夫ですよ
>
> 1)Why is it saying "Is it okay if you don't go home?" 「帰{かえ}らなくていいんですか。」

Yes.  It is saying "Don't you have to leave?", "Don't you have to go home?", etc.  My assumption here is that this conversation is taking place at the workplace.

> 2)What does 「ここから電車{でんしゃ}で二{ふた}つ目{め}」 mean?

「二つ目」 in this context means 「二つ目の駅{えき}」 ("the second train station (from here)").  The Hall is only two train stations away from where the conversation is taking place.

For those unfamiliar with this use of 「目{め}」, [this Q&A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14733/what-is-the-correct-way-of-saying-third-in-different-contexts/14735#14735) might be of help.

Japanese is an extremely contextual language, I must keep reminding everyone, myself included.

Comment: なるほど。手伝っていただいてありがとうございます

Comment: @ラゴズ Though I don't think disposing of everything by "contextual" is a good idea, n-つ in the transportation context certainly usually means the number of stops.