# What's the difference between the -banme and -ban counters?

Tags: grammar, translation, counters

I found these two sentences in RosettaStone

> kochira no sanbanme no seki desu

> kanojo wa hachiban no seki ni suwatte imasu

Why is the first one not "sanban" and the second one not "hachibanme"?

Answer (score 5):

You can think of it like

> *◯-ban* ↔ no. ◯
> *◯-banme* ↔ ◯<sup>st,nd,rd,th</sup>

so

> *sanbanme no seki* = the third seat
> *hachiban no seki* = seat no. 8

---

There are a few related questions, but they usually use *hiragana* and *kanji*:

- [What is the correct way of saying "third" in different contexts?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14733/1628)
- [「二番」 vs. 「二番目」 confusion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13009/1628)
- [Why is this [二番目]{に・ばん・め} counter used for a person?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15613/1628)